# Can I use a strange specialized killstreak weapon to fabricate a professional killstreak kit?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Can I use a strange specialized killstreak weapon to fabricate a professional killstreak kit?

Comment: You should always *try* to include more information in your question body (Why do you want to do this? What have you tried so far? That kind of stuff).  Whether or not the question title is enough, short question bodies are almost always frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Basing this answer off of https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit_Fabricator as well as when I created my own specialized and professional kits.

Long story short, you need to have it in Unique quality, as no other quality will fit the criteria for the fabricator. The easiest way to obtain them would be to buy an already killstreak or already specialized killstreak unique quality weapon off of the steam community market, as this is generally cheaper than buying the killstreak / specialized killstreak kit of one and applying it to your own item, only to then use that weapon in the fabricator.